# Why am I getting NaN for a result which should exist

Tags: r

I have the following code for generating random variables in R

```R
theta<-1

n<-1000  
u<-runif(n)
H<-(-theta*log(1-u)^(1/3))
```

My problem is that the output I'm getting for H is NaN 1000 times as the output when I know that the answer is real. Is there something wrong with the way I defined H?

Comment: @Gregor I don't really understand your math. If u is between 0 and 1 then 1-u will be between 0 and 1 not -1 and 0....?

Comment: @MikeH. doesn't help, cube roots of negative numbers are still negative (and R won't calculate them that way anyway).

Comment: Ahh, you're right. But `log(1 - u)` will be negative, and R doesn't like roots of negatives. Try `(theta * abs(log(1 - u)) ^ (1/3))`. The `abs()` removes one negative sign, so take out the one in front of `theta` to keep it equivalent.

Comment: @MikeH. the function is -theta(log(1-u))^(1/3)

Comment: @Gregor I'm sampling positive values and now they are all negative

Comment: @d.b no 8charac

Comment: Maybe apply each step individually to see where your understanding doesn't match R's? `u` is between 0 and 1, and as you corrected me `1 - u` is also between 0 and 1. Then you take the log, which will be negative because all your values are less than 1. Next, in order of operations, is the `^(1/3)` and this is where you get the `NaN`s - in fact R doesn't like any non-integer powers of negative numbers. ....

Comment: This is explained in `help("^")`: *"Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why `(-8)^(1/3)` is `NaN`. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function pow for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result in many corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard."*

Comment: So if you want to use `^(1/3)` you need to make sure it's applied to something positive. And logs of numbers less than 1 are negative. One option, what I'm suggesting above is to replace `(log(1-u)) ^ (1/3)` with `-( (abs(log(1-u))) ^ (1/3) )`

Answer (score 4):

In order:

```
u = runif(n) # between 0 and 1
1 - u        # between 0 and 1
log(1 - u)   # negative real
log(1 - u) ^ (1/3)  # NaN because...
```

From `help("^")` *"Users are sometimes surprised by the value returned, for example why `(-8)^(1/3)` is `NaN`. For double inputs, R makes use of IEC 60559 arithmetic on all platforms, together with the C system function pow for the ^ operator. The relevant standards define the result in many corner cases. In particular, the result in the example above is mandated by the C99 standard."*

So whenever you raise `x` to a non-integer power, the answer will be `NaN` if `x < 0`. One option, to get a negative real result, is to raise the `abs(x)` to the non-integer power and then make the result negative. (More generally, we multiply by `sign(x)` so it still works for positive `x`.)

```
sign(log(1 - u)) * (abs(log(1 - u)) ^ (1/3)) # Negative real, based on your inputs

-theta * sign(log(1 - u)) * (abs(log(1 - u)) ^ (1/3)) # Maybe what you want?
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sign(log(1 - u))`